# d3 Accessor Function Iteration

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js, multidimensional-array

This is my data.

```
let data = [
    {
      "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
      "ubiome": [
            {
              "count_norm": 1283,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides fragilis",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "count_norm": 3708,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "count_norm": 731,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "count_norm": 62226,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "count_norm": 2139,
              "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
      "ubiome": [
        {
          "count_norm": 1283,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides fragilis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "count_norm": 3708,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "count_norm": 731,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "count_norm": 62226,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "count_norm": 2139,
          "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

I am trying to use d3 to build a heatmap.  I know I need to use an accessor function to use the sample dates and, tax_name, and count_norm to plot the x, y and rect values.  I just can not get the accessor function to get past the first level of the data....

```
var cells = svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(data)
      .enter().append('g').append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'cell')
      .attr('width', cellSize)
      .attr('height', cellSize)
      .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.name); })
      .attr('x', function(d) { return xScale(d.rank); })
      .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.value); });
```

How do you build an accessor function to get at more nested data?

This is an update on where I am at.  I can not get the x & y pos to work in the data.

```js
let data = [{
    "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ubiome": [{
        "count_norm": 1283,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides fragilis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 3708,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 731,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 62226,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 2139,
        "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sample_date": "2017-07-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ubiome": [{
        "count_norm": 1200,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides Noway",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 3700,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 700,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 62000,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 2100,
        "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var dates = [];
var ubiomeonly = [];

var itemSize = 30,
  cellSize = itemSize - 1,
  margin = {
    top: 120,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 110
  };

var width = 750 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var adate = moment(data[i].sample_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  dates.push(adate);
};

var bacteria = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  bacteria.push(data[i].ubiome.slice(0, data[i].ubiome.length));
}
var bacteriaList = d3.merge(bacteria).map(function(d) {
  return d.tax_name
});
bacteriaList = d3.set(bacteriaList).values();

var x_elements = dates,
  y_elements = bacteriaList;

var xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(x_elements)
  .range([0, x_elements.length * itemSize]);

var xAxis = d3.axisTop()
  .scale(xScale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

var yScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(y_elements)
  .range([0, y_elements.length * itemSize]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain([0, 10000])
  .range(["#2980B9", "#E67E22", "#27AE60", "#27AE60"]);

var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
  .data(data)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var cells = svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.ubiome;
  })
  .enter().append('g').append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'cell')
  .attr('width', cellSize)
  .attr('height', cellSize)
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return yScale(d + i);
  })
  .attr('x', function(d) {  return xScale(d.sample_date); })
  .attr('fill', function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.count_norm);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .selectAll('text')
  .attr('font-weight', 'normal');

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll('text')
  .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("dx", ".8em")
  .attr("dy", ".5em")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(-65)";
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>uBiome Bacterial Counts</h1>
    <div id="heatmap"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nested selections. With two `selectAll().data().enter()` cycles we can append nested children elements in parent elements - each element with its own datum. With only one `selectAll().data().enter()`, we are only creating elements in the DOM for each item in the data array. Each item in the data array may have some property which itself is an array (or be a data array itself) - but you aren't actually doing anything with the child arrays yet.

Since you only have two items in your array, only two elements will be created. Since neither of those items have a `name` or `rank` property, accessing these properties will result in undefined.

Here's a simplified example of your code above, I append a `p` for each item in the example data array. Each `p` has its text set to be the datum for that element. The nested data is still just a property of the datum of each `p`. As your example data array has two items, only two elements are created:

```js
let data = [{"sample_date":"2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z","ubiome":[{"count_norm":1283,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesfragilis","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":3708,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesthetaiotaomicron","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":731,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesuniformis","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":62226,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesvulgatus","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":2139,"tax_name":"Parabacteroidesdistasonis","tax_rank":"species"}]},{"sample_date":"2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z","ubiome":[{"count_norm":1283,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesfragilis","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":3708,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesthetaiotaomicron","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":731,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesuniformis","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":62226,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesvulgatus","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":2139,"tax_name":"Parabacteroidesdistasonis","tax_rank":"species"}]}];

var body = d3.select("body");

body.selectAll("p")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(function(d) { return JSON.stringify(d); })
  .style("background-color", function(d,i)  { return ["yellow","skyblue"][i]; })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

*In your example, you've used nested your elements in your example, a `rect` in a `g`, but you are appending one `rect` to each `g` (otherwise you would need to use another enter cycle) and the `rect` shares the same datum as the `g`, this will not create elements with the datum you want.*

Now that we have two (soon to be parent) elements with a datum that has the nested data as some property we can enter new elements for each parent. To do so, we can now do a `selectAll().data().enter()` cycle with these two elements. Remember that `d` below is the datum of each `p`:

```
var parents = body.selectAll("p")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("p");

var children = parents.selectAll("span")
 .data(function(d) { return d.ubiome; }) // d is the parent datum here : {"sample_date":"time","ubiome":[child,child]}
 .enter()
 .append("span")
 .attr("x", function(d) { })  // d is the child datum here
```

Here we create a selection of children to parents based on each parent's specific datum. Now we can use the property containing the information for each child by accessing the parent datum. The snippet below creates a parent `p` for each parent again (differentiated by color again), the child selection is uses the parent's datum and creates a `span` for each child (differentiated by border). I've set each span to show its datum. This gives us two parent `p`s, each with five child `spans`.

```js
let data = [{"sample_date":"2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z","ubiome":[{"count_norm":9876,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesfragilis","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":3708,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesthetaiotaomicron","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":731,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesuniformis","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":62226,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesvulgatus","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":2139,"tax_name":"Parabacteroidesdistasonis","tax_rank":"species"}]},{"sample_date":"2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z","ubiome":[{"count_norm":1283,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesfragilis","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":3708,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesthetaiotaomicron","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":731,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesuniformis","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":62226,"tax_name":"Bacteroidesvulgatus","tax_rank":"species"},{"count_norm":2139,"tax_name":"Parabacteroidesdistasonis","tax_rank":"species"}]}];

var body = d3.select("body");

var parents = body.selectAll("p")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .style("background-color", function(d,i) { return ["yellow","lightblue"][i]; })

var children = parents.selectAll("span")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ubiome; }) 
  .enter()
  .append("span")
  .text(function(d) { return JSON.stringify(d); })
```

```css
span { 
  display: block;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not access specific properties of the child `d` here, but you can see that the span's datum corresponds to an item a parent's ubiome array. So accessing specific properties of the children should be pretty straightforward.

---

Here's the above logic applied to your snippet:

```js
let data = [{
    "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ubiome": [{
        "count_norm": 1283,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides fragilis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 3708,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 731,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 62226,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 2139,
        "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sample_date": "2017-07-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ubiome": [{
        "count_norm": 1200,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides Noway",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 3700,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 700,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 62000,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "count_norm": 2100,
        "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var dates = [];
var ubiomeonly = [];

var itemSize = 30,
  cellSize = itemSize - 1,
  margin = {
    top: 120,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 110
  };

var width = 750 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

dates = data.map(function(d) { 
  return d.sample_date;
})


var bacteria = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  bacteria.push(data[i].ubiome.slice(0, data[i].ubiome.length));
}
var bacteriaList = d3.merge(bacteria).map(function(d) {
  return d.tax_name
});
bacteriaList = d3.set(bacteriaList).values();

var y_elements = dates,
  x_elements = bacteriaList;

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(x_elements)
  .range([0, x_elements.length * itemSize]);

var xAxis = d3.axisTop()
  .scale(xScale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
  

var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(y_elements)
  .range([0, y_elements.length * itemSize]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return  moment(d).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  });

var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain([0, 10000])
  .range(["#2980B9", "#E67E22", "#27AE60", "#27AE60"]);

var svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parents = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('g')
  .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(0," + yScale(d.sample_date) + ")" });
  
var children = parents.selectAll('rect')
  .data(function(d) { return d.ubiome; })
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'cell')
  .attr('width', cellSize)
  .attr('height', cellSize)
  .attr('x', function(d) {  return xScale(d.tax_name); })
  .attr('fill', function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.count_norm);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .selectAll('text')
  .attr('font-weight', 'normal');

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll('text')
  .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("dx", ".8em")
  .attr("dy", ".5em")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(-65)";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<h1>uBiome Bacterial Counts</h1>
<div id="heatmap"></div>
```

What have I done here?

First, but unrelated to nested data, I'm using band scales for both your days and species (these are scales designed for things that take up a specific width/height such as bar charts, they are still ordinal). I also don't convert your date string except to format the axis label to simplify the scale. *I also made x consistently refer to horizontal scales/data/axes and the same with y (hence why your axes are flipped, I also don't bind data to your svg since it is unnecessary)*.

Second I've created a group for each sampling period (the parent element). I apply a translate to these parent `g`s based on the scaled value of the date (contained in the parent datum). By doing this I treat each parent as a row (I only translate the y value). *While I didn't have to position anything in the text examples above, I applied background color instead*.

Third, I'm creating child elements for each parent, these are positioned based on the species (as the row has already been positioned with a translate on the parent `g`). The species is accessed from the datum of the child (rectangle) - an item in one of the second level arrays in the original dataset. To set each child's datum I'm using the parent's datum (d.ubiome - not the entire datum) in the nested `selectAll().data().enter()` cycle, just as in the above example with text.

*In this pattern each parent datum is an item in the original array. Each child datum is an item in some array contained in that child's respective parent's datum. Hence why we use `parent.selectAll().data(function(d) { return d.ubiome }).enter()`*

That's it. I'm not accessing any parent data for the children as the rows position the children, but if you needed to access parent data, you can use a few approaches, one is to select the parent from the accessor function:  `d3.select(this.parentElement).data()`, or to use a local variable.

---

*You might ask why doesn't d3 bind the nested data to the nested elements, which appears to be the behavior you had expected. More often than not nested elements share the same datum as their parent as this facilitates thing like labeling (circle and text in a parent g). Data with properties that contain arrays may allow multiple representations of the data (animating through time, different classifications or representations of the data, etc) and thus the arrays are not nested data that will be ever represented with their own elements. And sometimes datasets will have multiple properties that contain arrays (which themselves contain arrays, eg: geojson), how would this behavior know which array to use for the children?*

Comment: Hi Andrew,  I looked at your answer and it got me going further down the path, but I am still not able to translate a ul list to where the data needs to go on the rect shape.  I have edited my question to show where I am in the process.  I can get the graph to start to generate but the x y pos based on the data and scale do not come through.

Comment: @MikeNelson, You still need nested enter/update/exit cycles (you have bound data to the svg, but still haven't nested enters). With heatmap type data it is useful to consider rows as parent elements (`g`s) and the children as `rect`s with that row (as representing the columns present in each row) - similar to the parent `p` and child `span` structure (just with different elements) I used in my original example. I've updated the answer to apply the pattern to your data.

Comment: This was perfect!!!  What helps the most is your thorough explanation.  It helps to process what is actually happening.  I have been fumbling through this for days, but you made it perfectly clear.